# xdg-open uses wrong character encoding on LTSP

Tags: encoding, ltsp

I'm trying to open files in a local application on an LTSP system. But if the path name contains accented characters, like `é`, it can not be opened because the URI seems to be encoded wrong.

The problems seems to be located in the way gvfs-open sends the file URI:

```
gvfs-open /home/user/testé/test.mov
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/user/test303251/test.mov'.
```

Opening the same file from the application itself (using File > Open..) does not give any problems.

Spaces and comma's seem to be encoded differently, with %20, and do not give any problems.

```
gvfs-open /home/user/this is testé/test.mov
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/user/this%20is%20test303251/test.mov'.
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and filed a bug for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ltsp/+bug/1451915

It was caused by the way LTSP opens local applications: LTSP sets an X property containing the command and arguments, which is read on the client and then executed.

```
/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

gets replaced on the clients by

```
xprop -root -f LTSP_COMMAND 8s -set LTSP_COMMAND "/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U"
```

But this uses an 8 bit encoding.
If you change the "8s" to "8u" it will use an UTF-8 unicode string, which seems to fix the problem.

The file that needs to be changed is:

```
/opt/ltsp/i386/usr/bin/ltsp-genmenu
```